# Unable to drag marker on google map in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

I'm using `google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.24+1` plugin. I can't drag the marker inside map even though `draggable` property is set `true`. Whats wrong here? My code :

```
                return GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(placemark.position.latitude,
                        placemark.position.longitude),
                    zoom: 18,
                  ),
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(
                    <Marker> [
                      Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId("home"),
                        position: LatLng(placemark.position.latitude, placemark.position.longitude),
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                          title: placemark.name
                        ),
                        draggable: true,
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: (mapController) {
                    googleMapController = mapController;
                  },
                );
```

Comment: The marker can only be dragged after holding it for a few seconds. Did you do that?

Comment: @Alvindrakes ooh! Now its ok. Thanks.

Comment: @Newaj, does a marker 'jump' when you long click on a marker?

Answer (score 2):

You need to long press the Marker to trigger the drag event. To debug, you can use the [onDrag()](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker/onDrag.html) property to see if the drag event has been started.

Comment: is there a way to drag without long press?